# How do you take a string and then call a data frame with name = that string?

Tags: r, quantmod

The following code returns a string called "GLD".

```
CatItUp <- function(x){
    print(x)
}

CatItUp("GLD")
```

This code returns the tail of GLD prices. But obviously, because I've hard-coded GLD into the function.

```
IAmMoney <- function(x) {

    require("quantmod")

    getSymbols("GLD")

    tail(GLD)   

}

IAmMoney("GLD")
```

This does not return prices like the hard-coded version, but the "GLD" string like the CatItUp() example above. I don't know why.

```
IAmMoney <- function(x) {

    require("quantmod")

    getSymbols("x")

    tail(x) 

}

IAmMoney("GLD")
```

How can you pass 'GLD' to the quantmod::getSymbols function, inside the IAmMoney() function?

Comment: I took liberty to try and rename the question to reflect the crux of your problem. I'm not sure if I helped or hindered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you simply overlooking the fact that `getSymbols()` has an option `auto.assign` ?

So you may want this instead:

```
R> library(quantmod)
R> silly <- function(sym) {
+     x <- getSymbols(sym, auto.assign=FALSE)
+     tail(x)
+ }
R> silly("IBM")
           IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
2010-12-03   144.25   145.68  144.25    145.38    3710600       145.38
2010-12-06   144.54   145.87  144.52    144.99    3321800       144.99
2010-12-07   146.02   146.30  143.87    144.02    4828600       144.02
2010-12-08   144.35   145.65  143.84    144.98    4961400       144.98
2010-12-09   145.94   145.94  143.52    144.30    4405300       144.30
2010-12-10   144.88   144.95  143.73    144.82    3503800       144.82
R> silly("C")
           C.Open C.High C.Low C.Close   C.Volume C.Adjusted
2010-12-03   4.38   4.46  4.35    4.45  360277300       4.45
2010-12-06   4.45   4.50  4.43    4.45  445170000       4.45
2010-12-07   4.55   4.65  4.54    4.62 3265796000       4.62
2010-12-08   4.61   4.64  4.55    4.64  913820900       4.64
2010-12-09   4.68   4.71  4.64    4.69  731119000       4.69
2010-12-10   4.70   4.77  4.66    4.77  763156100       4.77
R>
```

`getSymbols()` default behaviour of "I will stick it into your environment as a new variable" is more or less a design flaw and, as I recall, recognised as such.

And hence the behaviour can be altered by `auto.assign`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had totally overlooked that in the documentation. So one could simply do `tail(getSymbols("GLD", auto.assign=FALSE))` Nifty. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is perfect for the quantmod package. Simple and clean.

Answer (score 3):

Will `tail(get(x))` work?

Comment: Thanks ahala. In the back of my head I was thinking there has to be "A Better Way".

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful for non-quantmod functions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky because quantmod creates a data frame who's name is the same as the string you assign to x. So at first you need a string value then later you are calling a data frame by the name of x. This is exactly what do.call() is helpful for.

```
IAmMoney <- function(x) {
    require("quantmod")
    getSymbols(x)
    tail(get(x))
    # changed to get(x) per Ahala's input below. 
    # if you had many params you were passing, do.call()
    # might make more sense
}

IAmMoney("GLD")
```

Dirk pointed out that the use of the `auto.assign=FALSE` argument which means you can simply do this instead:

`tail(getSymbols("GLD", auto.assign=FALSE))`

Comment: Nice. It works. I need to comprehend that compact little line of code.

Comment: do.call() took me a while to fully appreciate as well.

Comment: so getSymbols accepts the string and creates the GLD object? And to use 'GLD' again as a simple string and not a dataframe, you coerce it back to a name? And why list?

Comment: do.call() requires a list as the second argument, so forget that question.

Comment: yes, getSymbols() takes a string. If it finds a symbol that matches the string it makes a data frame by the same name. So when you call tail() you are tailing the data frame. So in that case you don't want to pass tail() a string. You want to pass it the name of a data frame. That's what do.call does. The only thing tricky with do.call() is that it wants the arguments as a list.

Comment: from the documentation: A ‘name’ (also known as a ‘symbol’) is a way to refer to R objects by name (rather than the value of the object). I got it now.

Comment: Epic Fail Code! Surely the R-ish way would be if getSymbols returned an object rather than magically creating something. GLD = getSymbols(x) where x is the string"GLD"would be the right way... *facepalm*

Comment: @spacedman, yes getSymbols() is atypical, by design. The authors did it this way, I believe, to more easily mimic the work flow used by analysts. But this was a conscious decision as is evident in the documentation: "The previous sentence's point warrants repeating - getSymbols is called for its side effects, and does not return the data object loaded."